# Automatically opening a file in emacs by specifying the file name

Tags: emacs, ctags

I created a TAGS file for emacs in my django project using the following command on my Linux machine

```
ctags -eR *
```

I can now jump to a symbol definition using M-. and specifying the symbol name.In my project i have py,html and css files so is there also a way i can make emacs automatically open a file, if i specify the file name ?.

Thank You

Comment: Usually, I use find-file (C-x C-f by default) to open a file by specifying its name, but that's probably not what you are asking for. Please clarify your question.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.If i use C-x C-f then i have to specify the file path as well. What i meant was is there a way to make emacs index the file locations as well, so that specifying the file name would be enough information for emacs to open it,instead of requiring the full file path ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for project management. There are few packages to manage project directory in emacs. The best one may be `ede`. but Its not easy to setup. It does have some learning curve and its limitations.

Thankfully there are many easy ones. like eproject. https://github.com/jrockway/eproject/wiki

anyway you can also check out emacswiki page for more details. http://www.emacswiki.org/ProjectSettings

Comment: Will definitely check this out. Thanks for sharing :)

Answer (score 1):

http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/find-file-in-tags.el

Comment: A down-vote? Seriously? I interpreted the question as "how can I open a file indexed in my TAGS file by specifying its filename", and this library does *precisely* that.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments, I figured that you are looking for has nothing to do with tags, you just want a better find-file that makes good automatic guesses for the path given only the file name.

For this, I use the entirely awesome `ido-mode`: http://emacswiki.org/emacs/InteractivelyDoThings

Comment: Have you tried helm?  I prefer it for matching long strings like filenames.

Answer (score 0):

IDO ([Interactive Do](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/InteractivelyDoThings)) mode does this. If you activate it, C-x C-f searches for files matching what you are typing, interactively. Beware though, it may take some time to get used to it.

[edit] The search is based on files or directories you've recently visited, and you can use M-s to force a search.